# Subview-title not displayed properly using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a tableview and a detailview, connected with segues. 
I want the detailview's title to be the title of the selected cell.

If I use this code in `GradeDetail.m`, it works, but is static, of course:

```
self.navigationController.title = @"Title goes here";
```

If I use this on the other hand, it doesn't work, but should be dynamic:

```
self.navigationItem.title = grade.fag;
```

I have the class `Grade` imported where necessary and "fag" *(means "school subject" in Danish, not gay)* property defined in the class.

Here is an excerpt of the code from the tableview:

```
...
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) 
{
    grades = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Grade* grade = [[Grade alloc] init];
    grade.fag = @"Dansk";
    grade.mundtlig = @"7";
    [grades addObject:grade];

...    

}
return self;
}
```

And the code pushing the detail-view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{    
 GradeDetail *detailViewController = [[GradeDetail alloc] init];

Grade* grade = [self.grades objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.grade = grade;

//[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Notice from the above code, what I commented out:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

If I remove the segue in the storyboard, and use this line of code instead, the detail-view shows the correct title, but the view isn't loading correctly. *(Read: I don't want to use this line of code, I want it to work in storyboard.)*

Please tell me if you want to see more of the code or have some of the above clarified.

Comment: So in the case where you are using the segue, are you setting the detail view controller's grade property in your prepareForSegue:sender: method?

Comment: I'm not setting the detail view controller's seque programmatically. But I'll look into the method you mentioned.

Comment: Well, then that will fix it. That method is your opportunity to configure whatever you need to configure on the view controller which is about to be presented. You can set the grade property there just as were doing in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override `-prepareForSegue:sender:` to get a hook into the incoming view controller and set any properties required. You'll also need to specify segue identifiers in the storyboard.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowGradeDetails"])
    {
        GradeDetail *detailViewController = (GradeDetail *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Grade *selectedGrade = [self.grades objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
        detailViewController.grade = selectedGrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working, thanks a lot! I found out I didn't make an IBOutlet for the tableView, so I couldn't define self.tableView and I also had the identifier "ShowGradeDetails" on the table-view and not the segue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the viewController's title: `self.title = grade.fag;`

Comment: If you mean I should remove "navigationItem" from     self.navigationItem.title = grade.fag; that doesn't work either.